# Count records for first day of every month in a year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 4 columns huge number of records. It has the following structure:

```
DATE_ENTERED    EMP_NAME     DATA       ORIGINATED
01-JAN-20        A          545454        APPLE
```

I want to calculate no of records for every first day of every month in a year

is there any way can we fetch the data for every first day of month.

Comment: What is you actual query? you can pick date and month manually or you need something to pull records dynamically?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What is the output you want? One row for each month?

Comment: i'm using oracle DB and i need one row for each first day of the month.

Comment: @HemanthTanna It took some time to find out! let me know if that works. I have updated the answer under UPDATE section.

Comment: @HemanthTanna I have updated my answer under UPDATE-2, if that is what you're expecting then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle you can use `TRUNC` function on the date as follows:

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATE_ENTERED), COUNT(1) AS CNT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE TRUNC(DATE_ENTERED) = TRUNC(DATE_ENTERED, 'MON')
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE_ENTERED, 'MON')
```

Please note that the `TRUNC(DATE_ENTERED, 'MON')` returns the first day of the month for `DATE_ENTERED`.

Cheers!!

Comment: You have to modify the select query `Group By` and `Select`are different and it will throw group by error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Year, Month, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  YEAR(DATE_ENTERED) Year
  MONTH(DATE_ENTERED) Month
  DAY(DATE_ENTERED) Day
  FROM your_table
  WHERE DAY(DATE_ENTERED) = 1
) A 
GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Generally `WHERE DAY(DATE_ENTERED) = 1` will get you the records only for dates at the start of each month. Thus using Year and Month function you can group them by in order to get a count for each year and each month

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
select * from your_table
where DAY(DATE_ENTERED) = 1
and DATE_ENTERED between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31'
```

for number of count use this:

```
select count(*) from your_table
where DAY(DATE_ENTERED)= 1
and DATE_ENTERED between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31'
```

**UPDATE**

```
select * from your_table where Extract(day FROM DATE_ENTERED) = 1 and DATE_ENTERED between '01-JAN-20 ' and '01-DEC-20 ';
```

this is how the data looks like:

[image]

For the list of records

```
select count(*) from your_table where Extract(day FROM DATE_ENTERED) = 1 and DATE_ENTERED between '01-JAN-20 ' and '01-DEC-20 ';
```

[image]

**UPDATE-2**

```
select EXTRACT(month from DATE_ENTERED) as Count, 
to_char(to_date(DATE_ENTERED, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') from your_table 
where Extract(day FROM DATE_ENTERED) = 1 and DATE_ENTERED between '01-JAN-20 
'and '01-DEC-20 ' group by EXTRACT(month from DATE_ENTERED),  
to_char(to_date(DATE_ENTERED, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month');
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: But OP doesn't seem to have a day_of_month field, only a regular datetime field. That seems to be the point of the question.

Comment: Correct i dont have a coulmn day_of_month

Comment: i'm using orcle DB its throwing DAY is invalid identifier

Comment: @HemanthTanna: that's why you should always specify the DBMS product you are using: to avoid answers that don't work for you

Comment: @HemanthTanna It took some time to find out! let me know if that works. I have updated the answer under UPDATE section.

Comment: Hi Manju youre query is just giving the over all count of the data for all the first months combined. I'm try to get count for the each month's first day count for respective month.

Comment: @HemanthTanna I have updated the code now (UPDATE-2), let me know if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table 
WHERE DAY(DATE_ENTERED) = 1 AND
      YEAR(DATE_ENTERED) = Some_Year
GROUP BY DATE_ENTERED
```

You can also use `DATE_ENTERED BETWEEN 'YYYY0101' and 'YYYY1231'` (replace the YYYY with the year you want to retrieve data for) instead of `YEAR(DATE_ENTERED) = Some_Year`, if performance is an issue.